# Coulomb force on 2 plates with 2 layers of dielectrica in between

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, capacitance, dielectric

i want to calculate the force between 2 identical plates of a capacitor. the dielectrica in between the plates is composed of 2 layers, parallel to the plates. the upper layer is a liquid, while the lower layer is a solid. the lower dielectric is mechanically connected to the lower plate.

here my attempt of calculation:

the capacitor with the 2 layers is interpreted as 2 capacitors connected in series.
capacity1 = epsilon0 * epsilon1 * upper_plate / distance1
capacity2 = epsilon0 * epsilon2 * lower_plate / distance2
totalcapacity = (capacity1 * capcity2) / (capacity1 + capacity2)

total_charge = totalcapacity * voltage_between_plates
voltage_upperdielectric = total_charge / capacity1
voltage_lowerdielectric = total_charge / capacity2
fieldstrength1 = voltage_upperdielectric / capacity1
fieldstrength2 = voltage_lowerdielectric / capacity2

force between upper_plate and bottom of upper dielectric:
Fu = 0,5 * fieldstrength1 * total_charge
force between top of lower dielectric and lower plate:
Fl = 0,5 * fieldstrength2 * total_charge

what i really want to know is the force between the upper plate and the bottom of the upper dielectric.
is my way of calculation correct ? please help me to understand the physics of this type of capacitor